# Python: modify part of a string inside a .cfg file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to access a file (C:\Programmer\Test.txt
), find a string inside that file beginning with 'SS' and replace everything after that on the same line with a new string 'C:\Test\Flash'

The code below prints out the line I want to modify but I can't seem to find a suitable function that will replace everything after the 'SS' with the new string.

```py
import re
for line in open('C:\Programmer\Build\Test.txt'):
    if line.startswith('SS'):
        print(line)
        storedline = line
        print(storedline)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
file_path = 'C:\Programmer\Build\Test.txt'
new_line_content = 'C:\Test\Flash'
output = []
with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
    line = infile.readline()
    while line:
        if line[0:2] == 'SS':
            output.append('SS{}\n'.format(new_line_content))
        else:
            output.append(line)
        line = infile.readline()
with open(file_path, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join(output))
```

Note that here the detection of the line(s) `if line[0:2] == 'SS'` is based on interpreting literally your requirement 'find a string inside that file beginning with 'SS''